# fontawesome icon will not shown in firefox / edge

Tags: font-awesome

I am using fontawesome icons.
Works fine in all browsers.
But one icon will not shown (only in safari)

```
<i class="far fa-times"></i>
```

[image]

Chrome / Edge:

[image]

Firefox:

[image]

Any idea why ? :(

Comment: Any console errors?

Comment: no, nothing :( only warnings (other reasons)

Comment: other fontawesom icons will shown in firefox. only this one makes problem